# Translate transition reset position in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, transition

I'm trying to move a circle from (100,200) to (400,200) and after one cycle the circle should start moving from (100,100) to (200,100) and keep repeating that motion. After the first cycle I reset the position of the circle using circle.setCenterX(100) and circle.setCenterY(100). However, this is not reflected in the animation. The circle resets to (400,100) and keeps moving forward in the X direction instead of repeating the motion. I'm new to javaFX. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Test extends Application
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }

  final double lambda = 0.1; // pixel per millisecond
  double posX = 100;
  double posY = 200;
  double time = 0;
  double velocityX = 1*lambda;
  double velocityY = 0*lambda;
  Circle circle = new Circle(posX, posY, 20, Color.AQUA);
  Circle ref1 = new Circle(100, 200, 5, Color.CADETBLUE);
  Circle ref2 = new Circle(400, 200, 5, Color.CADETBLUE);
  Circle ref3 = new Circle(100, 100, 5, Color.CADETBLUE);

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
  {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.getChildren().addAll(circle, ref1, ref2, ref3);

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setCenter(pane);
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #29353B");
    double WIDTH = 800;
    double HEIGHT = 600;
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    move(3000);
  }

  public void move(double dt) // dt in milliseconds
  {
    System.out.println(circle.getCenterX()+", "+circle.getCenterY());
    TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(dt), circle);
    //translateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    translateTransition.setByX(this.velocityX*dt);
    translateTransition.setByY(this.velocityY*dt);
    translateTransition.setCycleCount(1);
    translateTransition.play();
    translateTransition.setOnFinished(actionEvent -> { updatePos(dt); move(2000); });
  }


  public void updatePos(double dt)
  {
    //this.posX += this.velocityX*dt;
    //this.posY += this.velocityY*dt;
    this.posX = 100;
    this.posY = 100;
    circle.setCenterX(this.posX);
    circle.setCenterY(this.posY);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TranslateTransition` modifies the `translateX` and `translateY` properties, not the `centerX` and `centerY` properties. If you modify the `centerX` and `centerY` properties when the animation is complete, you should also reset `translateX` and `translateY` to 0 for the circle to appear at those coordinates:

```
  public void updatePos(double dt) {
    //this.posX += this.velocityX*dt;
    //this.posY += this.velocityY*dt;
    this.posX = 100;
    this.posY = 100;
    circle.setCenterX(this.posX);
    circle.setCenterY(this.posY);
    circle.setTranslateX(0);
    circle.setTranslateY(0);
  }
```

Alternatively, you could use a `Timeline` instead of a `TranslateTransition` to directly manipulate the `centerX` and `centerY` properties in the animation:

```
public void move(double dt) /* dt in milliseconds */ {
    System.out.println(circle.getCenterX() + ", " + circle.getCenterY());
    double targetX = circle.getCenterX() + this.velocityX * dt;
    double targetY = circle.getCenterY() + this.velocityY * dt;
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(dt),
            new KeyValue(circle.centerXProperty(), targetX),
            new KeyValue(circle.centerYProperty(), targetY)));

    timeline.setOnFinished(actionEvent -> {
        updatePos(dt);
        move(2000);
    });
    timeline.play();
}

public void updatePos(double dt) {
    this.posX = 100;
    this.posY = 100;
    circle.setCenterX(this.posX);
    circle.setCenterY(this.posY);
}
```